# Populate Dropdownlist with Database value in Struts 2, Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, orm, struts2

I am trying to populate a drop down list with value from a table . The page uses strust2 and hibernate to access database.

I can get to view the registration page (which contains the drop down which has to populated with database values)
But no value appears in the drop down list.

**index.jsp**

```
  <s:url id="url" action="registerAction">

  </s:url>
  <s:a href="%{url}">Register</s:a>
```

register.jsp

```
 <s:form action="registerAction">
    <s:select label="Select Date of Month" name="months" headerKey="0" headerValue="--Select--"
                      list="allMonths" listKey="id" listValue="name"/>
    <s:submit value="Register"/>

 </s:form>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="registerAction" class="action.RegisterAction" method="populateSelect">
       <result name="none">register.jsp</result>
</action>
```

**month model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_mnth")
public class Month {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="mnth_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name="mnth_name")
    private String name;

    public Month(){}

    public Month(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public class UserDao {

 List<Month> allMonths = new ArrayList<Month>();
public List<Month> getAllMonths() {
        return allMonths;
    }

    public void setAllMonths(List<Month> allMonths) {
        this.allMonths = allMonths;
    }

    public Session getSession() {
        return HibernateUtil.getSession();
    }

    public void closeSession() {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    }

    public UserDao() {
    }

    public List<Month> getMonths() {
        Session session = getSession();
        Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
        allMonths = (List<Month>) session.createQuery("FROM Month").list();
        System.out.println("In constructor " + allMonths);
        t.commit();
        closeSession();
        return allMonths;
    }
}
```

**Action Class**

```
public class RegisterAction extends ActionSupport {
List<Month> allMonths = new ArrayList<Month>();
String months;
UserDao udao = new UserDao();

public List<Month> getAllMonths() {
        return allMonths;
    }

    public void setAllMonths(List<Month> allMonths) {
        this.allMonths = allMonths;
    }
    public String getMonths() {
        return months;
    }

    public void setMonths(String months) {
        this.months = months;
    }
    public String populateSelect() {
        allMonths = udao.getMonths();
        System.out.println("In constructor " + allMonths);
        return "none";
    }
    public RegisterAction() {}
}
```

Database table is `tbl_mnth` with fields `mnth_id`, `mnth_name`.

What i guesses from this is that the action class is not being instantiated. i don't know how or why it isn't being instantiated..

In server log it shows

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Month is not mapped [from Month]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate is an ORM (Object-Relational-*Mapping*) framework used to map POJOs to the database schema. In your case it's `Month`. And because you are using annotations to map the object to table you should configure it in the `hibernate.cfg.xml`

```
<mapping class="package.to.persistence.Month" />
```

Without mapping the class Hibernate can't find annotations in your object.

Comment: it works ..thank u..my mistake..spend atleast 2 weeks searchng in internet for this problem..

Answer (score 0):

try doing this in your DAO

```
public List<Month> getMonths() {
    Session session = getSession();
    Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
    allMonths = (List<Month>) session.createCriteria(Month.class).list();
    System.out.println("In constructor " + allMonths);
    t.commit();
    closeSession();
    return allMonths;
}
```

By the way it has nothing to do with your action class here becuase the exception is clearly a hibernate exception. Try putting a breakpoint (if you are using an IDE) in your action class, else put a System.out.println statement to see that your code is entering the action class.

Comment: the mistake was due to not adding mapping in hibernate config file..pointed out by Roman C..

thank you for lending your hand also..